# window.print not working after clicking once

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a print page button but it's not working after clicking once. This is my code

```
  $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  $('html').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast', 'swing', function () {
    var printContents = document.getElementById("shipping-reservation-
    summary").innerHTML;     
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;       
    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;      
    window.print();      
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    return false;
  })
```

Comment: Do you see any error in the console after the click?

Comment: @Ionut there's no error.

Comment: can you log the contents of `printContents`?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal I cannot see any logs for printContents even on first click

Comment: Maybe it crashes silently, can you put everything 3rd line onwards excluding the return statement in a `try...catch` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just hide the divs that you don't want to print

```
    const printDiv = () => {
        for (const element of document.getElementsByClassName('invoice-actions')) {
          element.style.display = 'none';
        }
        window.print();
        for (const element of document.getElementsByClassName('invoice-actions')) {
          element.style.display = 'block';
        }
        
        return false;
 };
```